# Solow model: effect on a sudden fall in population?

Tags: solow, capital

my question is, what happens in the Solow model when a sudden fall in population happens? let's say a bomb killed many people.

Comment: What happens to $\frac{K}{L}$ if L goes down? Does the steady state change if ***s, g, n $\delta$*** remain the same?

Comment: so a sudden drop in population affects (L) not (n)?

Comment: @MouradAlkalza yes L is the amount of labor given by population while n is the population **growth**. Also this is classical homework question on solow-swan model, on this site we have policy that homework questions should be first attempted by the user and user should show us that by posting the attempt together with question. If you want some detailed answers you should do that.